# Mass Mailer similar to Mailchimp?

Tags: email

Does anyone have any mailing software ideas similar to mailchimp I can install on my vps? I need to mail 5000 emails per week.

Comment: If the answer does not work for your pm me and Ill try to add in more :)

Answer (score 0):

I used "[Citadel](http://www.citadel.org/doku.php/installation:easyinstall:start)" a lot a few years ago (but we switched to Flowmailer (online mailer) since out customers wanted that). Should take you less than 30 minutes to set up (they provide an fairly easy installer).

- [Install instructions for Ubuntu](http://www.citadel.org/doku.php/installation:debian).